# PowerShell Compare-Object SideIndicator

Tags: windows, shell, powershell

PowerShell Compare-Object  SideIndicator

I have this code, which its output is not as intended

```
Compare-Object $(Get-Content c:\Folder\List1.txt) $(Get-Content 
c:\Folder\List2.txt) | 

Out-File C:\Folder\filename.txt
```

I only want to get the " => SideIndicator " Values only not both . I.e what is different in list2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-6) cmdlet to filter by the `SideIndicator` property (PSv3+ syntax):

```
Compare-Object (Get-Content c:\Folder\List1.txt) (Get-Content c:\Folder\List2.txt) | 
  Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '=>' | 
    Out-File C:\Folder\filename.txt
```

<sup>Also note how just `(...)` is sufficient to provide a single command or expression as an argument - no need for `$(...)`.</sup>

Note:

- Filtering by `=>` outputs only those lines that are unique to the RHS (`-DifferenceObject`) collection; the `SideIndicator` property value (which is a string) points in the direction of the collection that a given object is unique to (assuming positional argument passing):

  - `<=` ... unique to the LHS (implied `-ReferenceObject` parameter)
  - `=>` ... unique to the RHS (implied `-DifferenceObject` parameter)
  - `==` ... present in both collections (only with `-IncludeEqual`)
- However, on output [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object) *wraps* the original objects by default, namely in a custom object that has a `.SideIndicator` property and an `.InputObject` property, the latter containing the original input object, which results in output such as:

  ```
  InputObject                   SideIndicator
  -----------                   -------------
  unique line 1 from List2.txt  =>
  unique line 2 from List2.txt  =>
  ```
- To save *just the lines* in the output file, add the `-PassThru` switch to the [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object) call.

  - Note: The reason that filtering by the `.SideIndicator` property still works in this case is that with `-PassThru` the original objects are *decorated* with this property, using PowerShell's [ETS (Extended Type System)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6763).
  - For strings, this extra property is ignored when they're saved to a file, such as with [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file); however, in other scenarios it may surface; to prevent this:

    - Do *not* use `-PassThru`
    - Add an additional pipeline segment that pipes the `Where-Object` output to
      `ForEach-Object InputObject`, which outputs the undecorated original objects.