# Powershell Compare-Object missing SideIndicator

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise, compareobject

I have this following code

```
$filenameFormat1 = "new_permission.txt" 
$approvedLogsName = "last_permissions.txt"
Compare-Object -referenceobject $(get-content "E:\\logs\$approvedLogsName") -differenceobject $(get-content "E:\\logs\$filenameFormat1") | 
Out-File E:\\logs\output.txt
```

When I run this code in the PowerShell ISE, I get both '<=', '=>' Side Indicators. But If I run it on normal PowerShell or CMD, the SideIndicator is completely  missing.

There's no error messages.

I tried adding the where-object as in this question [PowerShell Compare-Object SideIndicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53361968/powershell-compare-object-sideindicator). If I run it with

```
where-object -eq '=>'
```

It prints the all the list items which are '=>' but if I change the side, the result again missing the SideIndicator completely

Any tips or suggestions will be highly appreciated

Comment: It works for me.  Can you show the contents of the two files, at least enough to reproduce the problem?  `where-object -eq '=>'` gives me a syntax error.  Note that compare-object sorts the two files before comparing them.  Out-file will convert the result to text and add formatting.  No indicators could also mean the files are equal, or you're comparing two empty files.

Comment: I suggest adding the output of `$PSVersionTable` to your question. I have personally had some odd new issues with output in PowerShell 7 (very recent release) which I didn't see on Windows PowerShell 5.1 or PowerShell 6.x.