# How do I convert an object to a Hashtable in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, collections, hashtable

I have a variable which is declared as (for example)

```
$dict_object = @{Firstname="A";Lastname="B"}
```

I want to run another command , any command for example, `Get-CIMInstance -class win32_BIOS` and I wanted to compare the output with the $dict_object variable using compare-object. The problem is that the $dict_object is a hashtable whereas the command output is not a hashtable. This is just example but is there any way to convert Powershell command output into a hashtable and compare it with a Hashtable variable/object. I tried using Convertfrom-stringData but it is not assigning key value pairs as expected.

**For example, this is the command with convertfrom-stringdata**

```
PS C:\Windows\System32> Get-CimInstance -class win32_bios | ConvertFrom-StringData
Name                           Value
----                           -----
Win32_BIOS: 1.6.0 (Name        "1.6.0", SoftwareElementID = "1.6.0", SoftwareElementState = 3, TargetOperatingSystem =…
```

**versus normal output**

```
PS C:\Windows\System32> Get-CimInstance -class win32_bios

SMBIOSBIOSVersion : 1.6.0
Manufacturer      : Dell Inc.
Name              : 1.6.0
SerialNumber      : BDM8P93
Version           : DELL   - 20170001
```

I am expecting the above to has first column as key and second column as value but it seems ConvertFrom-StringData is not working that way.

I need this to compare existing variable with output from Get-WebconfigurationProperty (IIS Module) and if the value is not right, then else block will execute Add-webconfigurationProperty where I have tested that the Add-webconfigurationProperty takes HashTable as input

Comment: Why compare a hash table to an object with referenceable properties? You could easily turn your hash table into a custom object and then compare properties with `Compare-Object` -> `$dict_object = [pstcustomobject]@{Firstname="A";Lastname="B"}`

Comment: Cannot use [pscustomobject] as the output of a command with values are not known earlier to create it.

Answer (score 1):

- [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance) outputs (non-string) *objects*, not strings, so its output cannot meaningfully serve as input to [`ConvertFrom-StringData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata), which expects strings in a specific format.
- While you cannot (directly) convert *objects to [hashtables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables)*, you *can* directly convert preexisting<sup>[1]</sup> *hashtables to (`[pscustomobject]`) objects*; e.g.:

  ```sh
  $dict_object = 
  $object_from_dict = [pscustomobject] $dict_object
  ```
- And, of course, you may directly a `[pscustomobject]` instance *directly*, as a *literal*<sup>[1]</sup>:

  ```sh
  $object = [pscustomobject] @{Firstname="A";Lastname="B"}
  ```

As [AdminOfThings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11025476/adminofthings) notes, once you have (non-hashtable) *objects* to compare, you can compare multiple properties across two [collections of] objects using the [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object) cmdlet, passing the set of properties to compare the objects by to the `-Property` parameter:

```sh
# Reference object (the one with comparison values).
$refObj = [pscustomobject] @{ Manufacturer = 'Dell Inc'; Name = '1.6.0' }

# Difference object (the one to compare against, from command output)
$diffObj = Get-CimInstance -Class win32_BIOS

# Compare the two objects, by the properties defined on the reference object.
Compare-Object $refObj $diffObj -Property $obj.psobject.Properties.Name
```

By default, `Compare-Object` outputs only those input objects that differ, wrapped in a `[pscustomobject]` instance with a `.SideIndicator` property indicating which input side the object is unique to; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53362088/45375) for more information.

---

<sup>[1] Creating `[pscustomobject]` *literals* even uses hashtable syntax (e.g., `[pscustomobject] @{Firstname="A";Lastname="B"}`), but that is actually *syntactic sugar* that constructs the object directly, not via an intermediate hashtable. Also note that such a literal preserves the definition order of the keys / property names, unlike true hashtables.</sup>

Comment: I have given the example as it stated here in this forum. In ideal situation, comparing a dictionary value which is predefined to output of a command where I expect the command output to anything and the comparison is not going to be between properties of 2 objects rather it is going to be the object itself. So, by all means, I am hearing that the output of a powershell command cannot be converted into a hashtable object to compare with another dictionary and only the properties of 2 objects can be compared.

Comment: @VijayanandA, Alex_P's answers shows you how to construct a hashtable from the properties of an object (this could also be done without knowing the property names ahead of time). As for comparing objects by properties: you can pass any number of properties to `Compare-Object`'s `-Property` parameter. I don't understand the _is going to be the object itself_ part of your comment. Objects as a whole - unless they are instances of .NET value types - typically don't compare meaningfully, if they are distinct instances.

Answer (score 0):

I would run the `Get-CimInstance` once and populate a hashtable according to the values you need.
For example:

```
$cimInstance = Get-CIMInstance -class win32_BIOS
$cimHashTable = @{
  Name = $cimInstance.Name
  Version = $cimInstance.Version}
}
if ($cimHashTable.Name -eq 'CorrectValue')
{
  continue
}
else
{
  Fix-Value
}
```

However, in this case I actually wouldn't make the effort and create a new HashTable but just use the `$cimInstance` variable and check for the values directly.